# CI Build with more than one Repository

Tags: git, tfs

I have migrated a legacy visual Studio Solution from SVN to TFS 2013 GIT. The solution has three projects. The solution file and two projects are stored in repository A and the third project (Library that is used in other solutions) is stored in repository B.

When I try and create a build definition under Source Settings I can only select one repository, which means when the build is performed the source from the other repository is missing and the build fails.

Does anyone know of a work around for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do one of two things:

1. (prefered) create a NuGet package - package your separate project as a Nuget package and drop it to a NuGet repo... Which could just be a network share. Then you take a dependency on the NuGet package instead. Build separately.
2. Make one repo - put all of your code into one repo.

It's up to you but the first option offers reuse where there second is hardcoded.

Comment: I want to add that, even if you can customize the Build template to Pull down another Repo, the CI will monitor only one Repo. In 2013 there is no direct support for Git subtrees or submodules.